# Sitecore Saturday 2017 - Dnipro, Ukraine

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

### Sitecore saturday

Sitecore Ukraine is holding a 1-day conference for engineers who work with Sitecore technlogies.

This event will include topics related to advanced development, deploying and debugging of modern Sitecore applications presented by senior technical guys from Sitecore Ukraine.

---

**When**: April 1st, 2017

**Where**: *I Coworking Hub*. 
Chernyshevs'koho St 37, Dnipro (ул. Чернышевского 37, г. Днепр)

**Website**:
https://sitecoresaturday.com/

---

**Agenda**:

09-00 *Start* (6:00 UTC)

10-00 *Deployment of complex applications to the Azure Cloud (Sitecore Azure Toolkit, ARM, WebDeploy)*

11-00 *Rest API: A way to go*

12-00 *Advanced techniques of the remote debugging*

13-00 - Onwards : TBD (10:00 UTC)

Comment: UTC times, please

Comment: Event created. It will appear in the sidebar 10 days in advance.